# Spring OAuth2 disable HTTP Basic Auth for TokenEndpoint

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am starting with Spring OAuth2. So far so good, I have secured my app with the configuration. But I have an issue, my client does not support HTTP Basic Authorization.

Is there a way how to disable HTTP Basic Auth for the /oauth/token endpoint? I would like to send the client_id and client_secret in the JSON body or in the request headers.

curl examples I would like to work:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"username": "user",
"password": "pass",
"grant_type": "password",
"client_id": "test-client-id",
"client_secret": "test-client-secret"
}' "http://localhost:9999/api/oauth/token"
```

OR

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Client-ID: test-client-id" -H "X-Client-Secret: test-client-secret" -d '{
"username": "user",
"password": "pass",
"grant_type": "password"
}' "http://localhost:9999/api/oauth/token"
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally figure it out. The way how to disable the HTTP Basich Auth is to enable a form authentication for clients. Just add those lines to your configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
  }
}
```

Now you will be able to send successful request to TokenEndpoint like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'username=user_username&password=user_password&grant_type=password&client_id=your_trusted_client_id&client_secret=your_trusted_client_secret' "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token"
```

But there is still remaining the ContentType application/json issue remaining. Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I think the problem of use JSON as input format is that if you change it, your server will not be OAuth2 compliant any more, because the RFC standard says that the request MUST be sent in form url-encoded format: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#appendix-B

Comment: I don't think that RFC specify there must be only one option for Content-Type in the request. The provided solution allow to use application/json and url-encoded both side by side. Of course there should be an option to enable/disable the JSON per client.

Comment: I did not read with a LOT of attention, but the pieces I did read seemed pretty tight on `x-www-form-urlencoded` requests. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3.2