# Is it possible to get an access_token from Spring OAuth2 server without client secret?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring Security's OAuth2 server implementation. I am trying to get the access_token from the servers' `/oauth/token` endpoint using the OAuth2 "Password" grant type by only supplying username and password and the client id without the client secret. 
This works fine as long as I provide the client id and the client secret in the `Authorization` header of my HTTP request like so:

```
curl -u clientid:clientsecret http://myhost ... -d "grant_type=password&username=user&password=pw&client_id=OAUTH_CLIENT"
```

Following the advice here: [Spring OAuth2 disable HTTP Basic Auth for TokenEndpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166613/spring-oauth2-disable-http-basic-auth-for-tokenendpoint), I managed to disable HTTP Basic authentication for the `/auth/token` endpoint. But when I tried to get the access_token via cURL like so:

```
curl http://myhost ... -d "grant_type=password&username=user&password=pw&client_id=OAUTH_CLIENT"
```

I got a `BadCredentialsException` and could see the message:

> Authentication failed: password does not match stored value

in my servers' log. At this point I was slightly irritated, because it was my understanding that this message only shows up when there's something wrong with the username and/or password, not the client id and/or secret. After additionally supplying the client secret in the cURL command like so:

```
 curl http://myhost ... -d "grant_type=password&username=user&password=pw&client_id=OAUTH_CLIENT&client_secret=SECRET"
```

everything was fine again.

So does that mean I have to supply the client secret one way or another to access the `/auth/token` endpoint?

PS: I am aware of the fact that regarding security it is generally a good idea to protect this endpoint via HTTP Basic authentication, but there are some use cases where one would rather be able to do without.

Edit:

I seem to have found a way to omit the client secret. Here's my OAuth2 server configuration (notice the calls to `allowFormAuthenticationForClients()` and `autoApprove(true)`):

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public OAuth2Config(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauth) throws Exception {
        // allows access of /auth/token endpoint without HTTP Basic authentication
        oauth.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();  
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
        .inMemory()
        .withClient("acme")
        .autoApprove(true) // <- allows for client id only
        .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password").scopes("openid");
    }

}
```

Edit II:

The question here: [Spring Security OAuth 2.0 - client secret always required for authorization code grant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785628/spring-security-oauth-2-0-client-secret-always-required-for-authorization-code) is very closely related to this one but deals with the OAuth2 grant type "Authorization Code", which results in a different workflow like the one you get with grant type "Password".

Comment: Can you see [this question](http://yon.ir/oauth2), please?

Comment: See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081799/3090180

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the specification (RFC 6749), if the client type of your application is ***public***, a client secret is not required. On the contrary, if the client type is ***confidential***, a client secret is required.

If Spring offers an API to set the client type, try to set the client type to *public*.

Comment: Accepted for pointing to the spec. Seems that the solution depicted in the edit to the question sets the client type to public just as required.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot's implementation requires that a client-secret be passed in to authenticate. You can however override this by creating a bean of type `AuthorizationServerConfigurer` and configuring it yourself. [This is the link to the documenation...](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html#boot-features-security-oauth2-authorization-server)

Answer (score 0):

Use basic auth but leave the password empty.

Answer (score 0):

In the implementation of `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` override `configure` and set password encoder to raw text encoder (do not use it as a default password encoder!).

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .passwordEncoder(plainTextPasswordEncoder())
                .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    private PasswordEncoder plainTextPasswordEncoder() {
        return new PasswordEncoder() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
                return !StringUtils.hasText(encodedPassword) || passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, encodedPassword);
            }

            @Override
            public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
                return passwordEncoder.encode(rawPassword);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Now, for OAuth client details (in memory or in a database), set the client secret to `null`. In this case, the client will be treated as public and will not require `client_secret` parameter. If you set client secret for OAuth client details (e.g. BCrypt hash), then the client will be treated as confidential. It will rely on default password encoder (e.g. BCrypt) and require `client_secret` parameter to be sent in order to obtain an access token.